# Google Chrome Extension - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia') (manifest V3) in background.js service_worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to use ***navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia*** and ***navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia*** in background.js in Manifest v3 for Google Chrome extensions and I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia')

Implementation

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function (stream) {
   
  })
```

The background.js is registered under *service_worker* key in manifest file using version 3. I need to use this function is background because the extension needs to record even when the popup is closed.

Comment: ManifestV3 background script is a service worker, so it doesn't have access to media. Write an html file, open it in a new tab and access the media there. Or add an extension iframe (web_accessible_resources ) to the current page.

Comment: So every time I open popup a new tab needs to get opened to use getDisplayMedia in the background?

Comment: @wOxxOm can you show me a minimal setup for this?