# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUserMedia') in background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Following several threads here on Stack Overflow I first request access to user media through an extension page, then send message to the background script to get user media from there. However I get the error that `navigator` isn't defined.

On a different note, I also get `Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.` and `Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL` errors in the background script even though I have set "<all_urls>" in host_permissions (MV3).

Here is part of manifest.json:

```
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "storage", 
      "activeTab", 
      "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      { 
        "resources": ["frame.html"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
      }
    ],
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      files: ['content-script.js']
    });
  }
})

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message) {
  if(message.from === 'success') {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: { echoCancellation: true }
      })
      .then((e) => {
        console.log('Started.');
      })
      .catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
  }
}
```

Content-script.js

```
function embedFrame() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('frame.html');
  iframe.setAttribute('allow','microphone *'); 
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

embedFrame();
```

frame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="getaccess"></button>
    <button id="msgbackground"></button>
    <script src="frame.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

frame.js

```
var button = document.getElementById("getaccess");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: { echoCancellation: true }
    })
    .then((e) => {
        console.log('Started.');
    })
    .catch((e) => {console.log(e);});
});

var button = document.getElementById("msgbackground");

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('hfafcmibegmeaajlogfpbijjfmoeknan', { from: 'success' })
});
```

Now, no matter if I open any tab and click button in injected iframe, or open frame.html directly using chrome-extension://.../frame.html, I get the following errors:

1. When I open frame.html directly, I can click the getaccess button and get asked for mic access, all good
2. When I open frame.html directly, click msgbackground button then i get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading getUserMedia)
3. When I open any tab and click getaccess button in iframe, get DOMException: Permission denied error (even if I have previously confirmed access through test 1
4. When I open any tab and click msgbackground button in iframe then i also get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading getUserMedia)

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ThomasMueller added code snippets

Comment: `Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.` occurs when you open a new tab, because extensions aren't allowed to inject content scripts into the new tab page.

Comment: `Error: Cannot access a chrome:// URL` occurs for the same reason, extensions aren't allowed to inject content scripts into chrome:// pages.

Comment: `navigator` isn't available in the service worker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010751/google-chrome-extension-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-readin

Comment: @ThomasMueller OK any idea how I can get user media from any tab but only ask for access once?